# How can I get a valid Firebase user JWT token

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-functions

Given that I have a Firebase project, but no development environment that supports the Firebase SDK, how can I get a valid Firebase JWT for one of the users in the Firebase project? I am able to create cloud functions in the project, and I tried making a function for this (in TypeScript), but to no avail:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

export const login = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const email: string = req.query.email || req.body.email;
  const password: string = req.query.password || req.body.password;
  admin.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  admin.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then((idToken: any) => {
    functions.logger.info("token: " + idToken, {structuredData: true});
    res.status(200).send(idToken);
  }).catch((error: any) => {
    functions.logger
        .info("could not get token: " + error, {structuredData: true});
   res.status(500).send(error);
  });
});
```

This code wont deploy due to these errors:

```
Property 'signInWithEmailAndPassword' does not exist on type 'Auth'.
Property 'currentUser' does not exist on type 'Auth'.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In firebase - How to generate an idToken on the server for testing purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268478/in-firebase-how-to-generate-an-idtoken-on-the-server-for-testing-purposes)

Comment: Those methods do not exist in Admin SDK. You'll have to use custom tokens with REST API as in above answer.

Comment: you can refer to this for more info on creating [custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the JS script I got from a colleague for this:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase/app");
const { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } = require("firebase/auth");

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "API-key-here",
  authDomain: "my-app.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://my-app-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "my-app",
  storageBucket: "my-app.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "sender-id-here",
  appId: "app-id-here",
  measurementId: "measurement-id-here"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = getAuth();
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, "user@example.com", "user-password-here")=
  .then((userCredential) => {
    console.log(userCredential.user.accessToken);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
```