# Disable backend to generate user id tokens

Tags: firebase-authentication

Seems like when using firebase, then the backend (that uses `firebase-admin` package) [is able to generate a custom token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268478/in-firebase-how-to-generate-an-idtoken-on-the-server-for-testing-purposes) for a user, and exchange it for an id token, which then can be used to authenticate this user.

But it seems a bit weird, why would a backend be able to auth any user without him? I mean, for Google OAuth2 I would need a user to actually click a Login button inside your Google popup to generate a login token (that I can later use to validate and authenticate the user), but with **firebase** seems like we don't need the user for his own authentication.

Why is it so and most importantly **can we block the backend to not be able to generate id token on behalf of a user**?

**--- EDIT ---**

The reason why I want to disable backend to generate custom tokens is because I want to create two web services: A and B, A interacts with the client's browser and with B, B is a backend service that interacts only with A. I want to ensure that when B gets an id token (from Google) B will be sure that it was generated by the real user, not by A.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: I'm not clear what your question is asking or where your concern lies.  What Firebase is doing is pretty standard for auth solutions where you need to implement your own auth provider.

Comment: I mean, for your Google OAuth2 I would need a user to actually click a Login button inside your Google popup to generate a login token (that I can later use to validate), but with firebase seems we don't need user for his own authentication.

Comment: Maybe you could edit the question to explain your scenario in detail and what you perceive to be the problem.

Comment: I'm still unclear what the problem is.  If someone has chosen to allow Google auth for their site, there would be no need for them to use the admin SDK on their backend to generate a custom token.  Custom tokens are only needed when using a custom auth provider (not one of the already-supported providers).  Why would you need to block something that doesn't need to be set up on a secure backend?

Comment: I see, I made one more edit to explain it better, hope it makes it clear now.

Comment: I still don't see what the problem is.  If A and B are both fully under your control, then you can be sure that are both only doing exactly what you want.  Why would one of them be doing something with the Admin SDK other than what you programmed them to do? Also, tokens aren't generated by users.  They are only generated by an authentication provider and delivered to users to they can authenticate future calls.